Xcode|CocoaPods: New files not appearing in SourceTree when created in submodules of iOS project
I am trying to create an iOS project with a multi-module architecture using CocoaPods local path. I use SourceTree to manage git.
Currently, I am facing an issue where new files created in the modules do not appear in the Unstaged files and Staged files sections of SourceTree. These files only appear when I create or modify them in the main module.

Podfile:

Project architecture: 


Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'MMCommon'
  s.version          = '0.1.0'
  s.summary          = 'A short description of MMCommon.'

  s.description      = <<-DESC
TODO: Add long description of the pod here.
                       DESC

  s.homepage         = 'https://github.com/dtrognn/MMCommon'
  s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'dtrognn' => 'dtrognn@gmail.com' }
  s.source           = { :git => 'https://github.com/dtrognn/MMCommon.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }

  s.ios.deployment_target = '16.0'

  s.source_files = 'MMCommon/**/*.{swift,h,m}'
  s.resources = 'MMCommon/**/*.{png,xcassets,json,ttf,txt,storyboard,xib,xcdatamodeld,strings}'
end

I have also tried to commit and push using Xcode's built-in source control, but no new commits are updated on my GitHub repository.
Can someone help me figure out what the problem might be?

Did you modify the gitignore? In Terminal, git diff doesn't show them?

I tried creating a new repository without a .gitignore file and still encountered the same issue.

I found the cause. When I created a new module, a .gitignore file was generated, but it was hidden, and I couldn't see it. I made it visible by pressing CMD + Shift + . and deleted it. The problem has been resolved.
